# How to display the sum of a function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I started learning Node.js and after I learned how to create and export modules and starting a server I decided to play a little and tried to display the sum of a function that I have created, however it does not display the sum, but NaN. How can I display the sum of the function on my localhost, here is my code:

app.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var Addition = require('./Addition');

var server = http.createServer((function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
response.end(`${Addition.AddNumber(1+3)}`);
}));

server.listen(7000);
```

Addition.js:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.AddNumber = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

What I have tried:

displaying it like this:

```
response.end(Addition.AddNumber(1+3));
```

and:

```
response.end(`${Addition.AddNumber(1+3)}`);
```

Which gives me the NaN.

Comment: `AddNumber(1+3)` is calling it with `a === 4` and `b === undefined`. The addition is happening *outside* the function, and `4 + undefined` is **N**ot **a** **N**umber. Did you mean `AddNumber(1, 3)`?

Answer (score 1):

use `AddNumber(1,3)`. By using `AddNumber(1+3)` what it's actually doing is `AddNumber(4,undefined)`

Comment: Parameters that aren't provided are `undefined`, not `null`. `4 + null` is `4`, not `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, argument passing is incorrect in your AddNumber function

```
var http = require('http');
var Addition = require('./Addition');

var server = http.createServer((function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
response.end(`${Addition.AddNumber(1,3)}`);
}));

server.listen(7000);
```